# Module import works differently for two ways of importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to teach myself tensorflow. The new version has keras built in.

I can access the `Dense` function in the following way

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.Dense
```

but this does not work:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Why is that? I notice that:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
```

Does work. When I import tensorflow, does it know to intelligently add the `.python` to the module name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [GitHub Repo for Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), if you look at the two `__init__.py` files inside `tensorflow-master/tensorflow/python/keras/` and `tensorflow-master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/`, you can see which modules are imported as part of the package structure. This determines what and how you as a user import things when using the package and its modules.

David Beazley has a really good talk on the innerworkings of this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0

Comment: great. so more crucially, when importing `tensorflow` it actually does: `from tensorflow.python import *` (you can see this from the `__init__.py` for tensorflow-master/tensorflow/ itself.